# Can I publish IOS apps for different clients to one account?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I'm looking for Info regrading the possibility of publishing my clients apps that our company developed through our App Store account. Is this allowed by Apple? or Should we purchase separate accounts for every client for hosting the apps?. (We have few big clients and trying to avoid any legal complications after publishing the apps).

Comment: The client should enter into the agreement with Apple and then give you the ability to publish apps through that program membership. Apple frequently rejects apps where the branding does not match the legal entity publishing the app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined by the [help]. If you have a question about complying with a company's product or service policies, you should ask them directly.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. If you're making an app for multiple clients using the same template, then it will get rejected. Apple made some changes regarding white label apps this year. It seems that your clients will have to purchase their own developer accounts to publish their apps.
From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) Section [4.2.6](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality):

> **4.2.6** Apps created from a commercialized template or app generation service will be rejected unless they are submitted directly by the
>   provider of the app’s content. These services should not submit apps
>   on behalf of their clients and should offer tools that let their
>   clients create customized, innovative apps that provide unique
>   customer experiences. Another acceptable option for template providers
>   is to create a single binary to host all client content in an
>   aggregated or “picker” model, for example as a restaurant finder app
>   with separate customized entries or pages for each client restaurant,
>   or as an event app with separate entries for each client event.

I've seen a few developer businesses walk their clients through the process of purchasing a developer account and making the developer a lead role in the client's team so that they may publish and maintain the app for their client while still using the client's developer account.
It might be a possibility for you too.